# ¿Como hacer que un EditText contenga un Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, recyclerview, edittext

*Tengo un `EditText` y necesito que **dentro** del contenido haya un `ReclycleView`* que ya aparecen separados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Dentro de un exit text no debería poner un recyclerView. El edit text es para introducir texto. Aún así, como comentaron antes, sería bueno que expliques mejor lo que intentas hacer.